# Как поменять размер шрифта у MultiLineEntry в fyne

Tags: golang

Я хочу увеличить шрифт в MultiLineEntry но не могу найти как это сделать.
В MultiLineEntry можно задать TextStyle но размер шрифта там не указан.

Так я создаю окно и поле ввода:

```
app := app2.New()
win := app.NewWindow("Test")
win.Resize(fyne.NewSize(900, 600))

entry := widget.NewMultiLineEntry()
win.SetContent(
    entry,
)
win.ShowAndRun()
```

Это всё что я смог поменять у TextStyle:

```
entry.TextStyle = fyne.TextStyle{
    Bold: true,
    Italic: true,
    Monospace: true,
    Symbol: true,
    TabWidth: 10}
```

Comment: у fyne.TextStyle  есть поле Size

Comment: и еще вы не сделали `entry.SetStyle(<fyne.TextStyle>)`

Comment: У меня выдаёт ошибку <unknown field 'Size' in struct literal of type fyne.TextStyle>. Версия golang - go1.19.4 windows/amd64, версия fyne - v2.3.1